# Can't use throw or raiseerror inside try..catch block in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure and I can't use Throw or `RAISEERROR` for some reason. I have to say I am a newbie in SQL Server, I have never used this statements before, but for some reason when I type them in doesn't turn blue.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[del_pay_plan_proc]
@id INT
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY

DELETE FROM test_table WHERE [Id] = @id;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

THROW

END CATCH
```

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

What can be the reason that I can't call the function `RAISEERROR` or use `THROW` statement?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: THROW doesn't exist in SQL Server 2008 R2. It was introduced in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: It's `RAISERROR` with just one `E`.

Comment: @Dems: It's exactly the RASERROR that was wrong typed. Thank you! Anyway the Sql Server 2012 is already out? Final version? I will have to put this database soon up and running. I am thinking now if it's better to put in their servers in 2008 or the 2012 version.

Comment: It's easy to remember the vowel shortage at Microsoft: `RaIsError` refers to the Sun god boo boo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding it should be like below...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[del_pay_plan_proc]
@id INT
AS
Begin Try
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET XACT_ABORT ON
    Begin Tran
         DELETE FROM test_table WHERE [Id] = @id;
         Select '' Msg
    Commit Tran
End Try

Begin Catch
    RollBack Tran
    Select Error_Message() as Msg
End Catch
```

By doing this, it is not required to throw any Exception if an error occurs. Control will automatically move inside Catch block in case any error occurs.

---

**[Reference from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx)**

Comment: Printing an error message if fundamentally different from raising an error message.  The OP just needs to replace `RAISEERROR` with `RAISERROR`.

Comment: @Dems - Sir, I excluded it because in case of error, control will move into catch block due to exception handling. So no need of it.

Comment: But the OP is trying to re-throw the error.  I presume after some clean up, logging, or other processing.

Comment: @Dems - sir, if that is the case, then there is no need of Exception handling as mentioned in OP's query. As, throw is being used in Catch block.

Comment: I didn't mention but i want to catch the error if it occurs in c# app side. That's why i was not trying to use the Print statement. I am not sure but i think i doesn't print the error to the application. Am i right? I am saying this because i tried but didn't work with the Print statement to catch the error in the App side.

Comment: @Miguel, I updated the code in the catch block. In case of error, it will select the `Error_Message()` and same will be sent to the `C# application`

Comment: You do need the execption handling. You could have code that does steps 1, 2 and 3, all in a try block. If any of those cause an error you clean up (rollback a transaction, etc), maybe do some logging, or other sql statements, then re-throw the error. The clean-up only happens because of the CATCH block, but you don't want a clean up to prevent the error from reaching the client (or further up the call try inside SQL StoredProcs), so you re-throw the error after the clean up, inside the catch block. It's really normal behaviour.

Comment: @Miguel - I have updated code. The select statement will send some message in case of error and `Transaction` will be `Rollback`. Otherwise it will send empty and `Commit Transaction`. You can use `DataReader` to read it in `C# Application`.